# Conceptual help with scalar invariance testing

Tags: measurement, scale-invariance, structural-equation-modeling, invariance

I'm having trouble understanding why scalar invariance is needed in testing a certain type of model.

Let's say I have employee and supervisor ratings of deviance. I want to look at what happens when the views are incongruent (supervisor says employee sucks, employee thinks they are great, etc.).

These will be latent variables of employee deviance. What I expect is that employees will say they aren't deviant at all and supervisors might be more honest (i.e., provide higher ratings of deviance). I would expect that the item means for each question will be higher for supervisors than for subordinates. So why would I need to demonstrate scalar equivalence? My understanding is that scalar equivalence requires item intercepts to be equal for the same item across raters. I would think that I would not want to see that as I already know going into it that supervisors will provide higher ratings on each item, not equal ratings....

any thoughts on this?